# jQuery Mobile page renders incorrectly unless refreshed

Tags: ajax, html, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am building a photo gallery page using jQuery Mobile 1.3.1 and Ajax to retrieve the photos from my PHP server in JSON format. When I navigate to the page for the first time the #album_loader div is displayed with nothing in the #album_message div (Yes, local storage variables are populated). According to my code, the #album_mesage div should have content in it and the #album_loader div should only show when the Ajax request is sent. I know jQM has some tricky ways to get things to render each time a page is viewed, but this same approach is working for my other pages. Any ideas? Below is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Wedding</title>
    <link href="css/jquery-mobile.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/application.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/global.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-mobile.js"></script>
    <script src="phonegap.js"></script>
    <script src="js/connection.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="album">
        <div id="header" data-role="header"><p align="center">Wedding</p></div>
        <div id="content" data-role="content">
            <div id="album_message" class="message" style="margin-bottom:20px;"></div>
            <div id="album_loader" class="message"><p align="center"><strong>Please Wait, Loading Album Data...</strong><br /><img src="images/loading.gif" /></p></div>
            <div id="album_photos"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            <nav data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html" data-icon="home">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="instructions.html" data-icon="info">Instructions</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script scr="js/fancybox.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#album', function() {
        $('#album_loader').hide();
        var album_id = localStorage.getItem('album_id');
        var album_title = localStorage.getItem('album_title');
        var album_bride = localStorage.getItem('album_bride');
        var album_groom = localStorage.getItem('album_groom');
        var album_user = localStorage.getItem('album_user');
        $('#album_message').html('<p align="center"><strong>Album:</strong> ' + album_title + ' <br /><strong>By:</strong> ' + album_bride + ' & ' + album_groom + '</p>');
        $.ajax({
            url: server_url + "get-photos", 
            type: "post", 
            data: 'album_id=' + album_id, 
            dataType: 'json', 
            crossDomain: true,
            beforeSend : function (){
                $('#album_loader').show();
            },
            error: function() {
                $("#album_loader").hide();
                $('#album_message').removeClass("message").html('<p align="center">Server communication error while trying to retrieve album photos.</p>').addClass("errorm");
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $("#album_loader").hide();
                if (data.response === "true") {
                    $("#album_photos").append('<div id="grid" class="ui-grid-b"></div>');
                    var photos = data.photos.length;
                    $.each(data.photos, function(i, object) {
                            $("#grid").append('<div class="ui-block-b"><img src="' + photo_url + album_user + '/thumbnail/' + object.photo_thumbnail + '" class="img-border" /></div>');
                    });
                } else {
                    $('#album_message').removeClass("message").html('<p align="center">Error retrieving photos.</p>').addClass("errorm");
                }
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, after refreshing the images do finally show and when I navigate away from the page and then back to it the images show twice. Why is that? Is it because I am appending to the div? How would I get around that?

Comment: For duplicate images, use `$('#album_photos').empty();` before inserting new images. Try `pageshow` to check if they are visible without refreshing.

Comment: The .empty() fixed the appending issue and I switched pagebeforeshow to pageshow, but I still get the same behavior. When I first go to the page the #album_message div is empty and the #album_loader div is shown.

Comment: Hmmm try `$('[data-role=content]').trigger('pagecreate')` or `updatelayout`, once you finish inserting photos.

Comment: I added that after the $.each and it still does the same thing. jQM is frustrating. It works fine when I navigate away and then back, but the first time is when it is broken.

Comment: I know..we can do another trial, insert photos before leaving the previous page `pagehide` or `pagebeforehide`, all you need to do is add `#album` to all your selectors.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this. My jQM knowledge is limited, but I don't understand why this isn't working on this page yet the same approach works on other pages. Of course those Ajax requests are activated by a form.

Comment: jQM enhances elements which are inserted into DOM dynamically as long as they are not yet shown. For elements inserted into active page, you need to force JQM to enhance them. My idea is to insert photos before page #album is active, so JQM recognises them and does its' magic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some close examination I figured out that the reason my code was not executing was because I had the JS outside of the body tag. Here is a working version of my page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Wedding</title>
<link href="css/jquery-mobile.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/application.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="css/fancybox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/global.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-mobile.js"></script>
<script src="phonegap.js"></script>
<script src="js/connection.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="album">
<div id="header" data-role="header"><p align="center">Wedding</p></div>
<div id="content" data-role="content">
<div id="album_message" class="message" style="margin-bottom:20px;"></div>
<div id="album_loader" class="message">
<p align="center">
<strong>Please Wait, Loading Photos...</strong><br /><img src="images/loading.gif" />
</p>
</div>
<div id="album_photos"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
<nav data-role="navbar">
<ul>
<li><a href="index.html" data-icon="home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="instructions.html" data-icon="info">Instructions</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
<script>
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#album', function() {
var album_id = localStorage.getItem('album_id');
var album_title = localStorage.getItem('album_title');
var album_bride = localStorage.getItem('album_bride');
var album_groom = localStorage.getItem('album_groom');
var album_user = localStorage.getItem('album_user');
$('#album_message').html('<p align="center"><strong>Album:</strong> ' + album_title + ' <br /><strong>By:</strong> ' + album_bride + ' & ' + album_groom + '</p>');
$.ajax({
url: server_url + "get-photos",
type: "post",
data: 'album_id=' + album_id,
dataType: 'json',
crossDomain: true,
beforeSend : function (){
                 $('#album_loader').show();
             },
error: function() {
$("#album_loader").hide();
$('#album_message').removeClass("message").html('<p align="center">Server communication error while trying to retrieve album photos.</p>').addClass("errorm");
},
success: function(data) {
$("#album_loader").hide();
if (data.response === "true") {
$('#album_photos').empty();
$("#album_photos").append('<div id="grid" class="ui-grid-a"></div>');
var html = '';
for (i = 0; i < data.photos.length; i++) {
html += '<div class="ui-block-b"><a class="fancybox" rel="gallery" href="' + photo_url + album_user + '/resized/' + data.photos[i].photo_resized + '"><img src="' + photo_url + album_user + '/thumbnail/' + data.photos[i].photo_thumbnail + '" class="img-border" /></a></div>';  
}
$("#grid").append(html);
$('#album_photos').trigger('create');
} else {
$('#album_message').removeClass("message").html('<p align="center">Error retrieving photos.</p>').addClass("errorm");
}
}
});
});
</script>
     <script src="js/fancybox.js"></script>
            <script>
$('.fancybox').fancybox({

});
</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

(keyboard gone mad but I really want to help. Don't notice the capitals).

I had the same problem awhile ago. The elements don't get initialised on page init or load.

But you can use a jQuery solution.

```
$("your element holder selector here").Trigger ("create");
```

Please take note, there was a jq mobile bug when I used it twice on elements in different pages.

There was a jQuery mobile method but its for list and I didn't get it to work properly on dynamically created html elements:

```
$('your element holder selector here').Listview('refresh');
```

Works only on pageinit for some reason.

For more info search for creating dynamic objects in jq mobile, there's also an example on http://jsfiddle.Net/elenj/101/

Alternatively if you don't bend and brake stuff with brute force.

You can always add the class and the span elements of jq mobile on your own.

Maybe create a fix function like that and add it as a plugin?

Oh and for the "why dose it happen" you add elements dynamically to a page after jq mobile did it magic on init and add all the class and span when paged loaded.

What you did is add it after that and hoped they had a function that updates all the elements every millisecond.

They have a func that deal with that the refresh list as I said before. Try both my solutions and if it wont work ill find another solution.

Comment: That did not work. I tried putting $(#album_photos).trigger('create'); after the $.each loop and it did the same thing.

Comment: IT WILL WORK IF YOU DO IT THE MOMENT IT CREATES ITׂ ON THE NEXT LINE.

PLUS I ADD SOME JSFIDDLE LINKS CHACK THEM OUT,THERS EVEN A BRUTE FORCE EXAMPLE,ITS BETTER TO HAVE SOME SOLUTION THEN NONE.